# What does it mean physically if pentagon identity or hexagon identity doesn't have any answers?

Tags: quantum-information, topological-field-theory, topological-order, anyons, topological-phase

Imagine I write a set fusion rule for some hypothetical anyons on a paper. Then, I try to solve Pentagon and Hexagon equations, imagine finally I find out, for example, the Hexagonal equation doesn't have an answer. So, what does it mean physically?

Does it mean we don't have such anyons in nature?

Comment: Strictly speaking there are no anyons in nature, at all. You may have model systems for anyons that will, for a short time, approximate the behavior of real anyones. Just because you fail to solve an equation doesn't mean anything for nature. It could mean that you are not good at math or that you are trying to solve an equation that nature doesn't care about. Having said that, I assume that there is actually an intelligent question in here, but you should try to formulate it as one.

Comment: @CuriousOne the question is in the title. I interpret it as asking whether all solutions to the fusion rules must obey those identities.

Comment: @MitchellPorter: "An identity not having an answer" is not in my physics language repertoire. I don't know what the OP means by that. Does he/she mean that there are no anyon solutions that satisfy the equations? Does he/she mean that he/she couldn't find solutions? Does he/she mean that the equations do not represent a valid physical question (like the question for the electrostatic self-energy in classical electromagnetism?) There are several possible scenarios here, and I have no way of telling which one  is of interest, especially since practical anyons are crude approximations, anyway.

Comment: If there are no solutions satisfying the pentagon and hexagon identities, then there is no theory of anyons for that fusion rule. If there are solutions, but the matrices are not unitary for any solution (this happens), then there is no physical theory of anyons for that fusion rule. Most fusion rules you could write down don't have corresponding anyons.

Comment: @CuriousOne I got the answer. But I ask it again in a different way. 
As maybe you know every anyon model corresponds to a unitary modular tensor category. So my question was about the vice versa case, the case when there is a fusion category which doesn't admit braiding or as was mentioned by Prof. Shor isn't unitary.

Comment: I don't think I am satisfied with Prof. Shor's answer, either. "There is no theory of" is not a meaningful physical expression, either. There is no classical theory of atoms, yet they exist and the answer is that the classical assumption is flat out wrong. The word "modular tensor category" doesn't impress me much, if that is what you are trying to do. What you are talking about here does not seem to exist in exact form in nature, to begin with, so you are theorizing about ideal symmetries of a non-ideal physical object.

Comment: @CuriousOne: If you don't believe anyons exist in nature, do you have an alternate explanation for the fractional quantum Hall effect?

Comment: Dear Prof. Shor, I don't believe in anything. To the best of my knowledge :-), the fractional Hall effect is experimentally established and has earned its discoverers a Nobel. Curiously, many people "knew" that it couldn't exist (based on symmetry assumptions?). A few years earlier people also "knew" that quasi-crystals couldn't exist, also based on symmetry assumptions. You will therefor excuse me that I don't "believe" any physical predictions based on symmetry/algebra etc. alone. Nature seems to have funny ways of getting around all of these things.

Comment: @CuriousOne: the physical prediction of anyons is not based solely on symmetry/algebra, but also on the fact that no other explanation is known for the fractional quantum Hall effect. Experimentalists are currently trying to provide conclusive evidence for the presence of non-abelian anyons in FQHE systems, and I am reasonably sure that they will do so within the next few years.

Comment: @PeterShor: I have little doubt that they will find something resembling an anyon. I don't know how much money I would bet on the words "conclusive" and "within the next few years", though. I have heard these words before... just after high temperature superconductivity had been observed. I remember that fifteen years later or so no conclusion had been reached and some people who had predicted quick success were eating their hats. After that I stopped watching.  Today, 29 years after the fact, the word "conclusive" still feels somewhat inappropriate for high-Tc theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pentagon and hexagon equations are consistency equations for the fusion and braiding of anyons. They should be satisfied by anyons realized in a gapped, local Hamiltonian. If you do not find solutions, then according to our current understanding of topological phase, yes, such anyons do not exist (in the sense that can not be realized by gapped, local Hamiltonian).